# Does this istance of the Poisson equations have solutions? If so, how many, and how to find them?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, poissons-equation

I know virtually nothing about PDE's. Actually, I'm asking this questions because I'm trying to help out a friend of mine, so, please, excuse any ignorant/nonsensical statement on my part and forgive me if the questions is not in line with the rules.

Consider the function $f:\mathbb{R^3}\rightarrow\mathbb{R} $ such that $$f(x,y,z)=\begin{cases}
1  & \text{if $z=0$} \\
0 & \text{if $z\neq0$}
\end{cases} $$

Is there a function $\phi$ such that $$\Delta\phi=f$$ where $\Delta\phi=\frac{\partial ^2\phi}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial ^2\phi}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial ^2\phi}{\partial z^2}$?

If so, is the solution unique? And how do I find it?

Comment: Classically, there is no solution. In the sense of weak solutions it is the same as the Laplace equation. Probably what you actually want is something like $f(x,y,z)=\delta(z)$, so that the overall plane $z=0$ carries some "charge" or "mass". As it stands you have essentially an infinitely thin plane with a finite charge density per *volume*, so it contains no charge and thus can't create a potential.

Comment: @Ian  Thanks for the answer. A few questions: 
1)Is $\delta (z)$ the Dirac delta function? I haven't seen any distribution theory yet, but I would be interested if you could explain briefly how modification changes the equation

2) Your statement that a thin plane can't create a potential seems odd to me. Aren't there examples in electrostatics which involve electric field/potential of charged planes?

Comment: 1. Yes $\delta$ is the Dirac delta function. The physical intuition is simpler than the math: $\delta(z)$ is 1 unit of charge per unit area concentrated on the plane $z=0$. 2. Yes, there are cases where you deal with charged planes, but they have finite charge density per *area*. Similarly charged lines have finite charge density per unit *length*. If you give them only finite charge density per *volume* then they cannot have any charge and so they cannot induce any potential. And the Poisson equation is how you compute this potential.

Comment: @Ian  in this case I have given a plane a finite charge density per volume... so, mathematically speaking, the Dirac delta is a way to endow a surface with a finite charge density per area?

Comment: That's right. ${}{}$